# How do I get cljx to compile clojure files into classes during uberjar?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, cljsbuild, cljx

I'm using cljx to build cli / cljs applications but haven't for the life of me been able to create a self packaged compiled jar.

Here's my project file -> https://gist.github.com/chrispwood/4db33e53555a8e8787d1

When I run `lein jar` or `lein uberjar` I get only a packaged jar with the clj files, not the class files. See the output file above ^^.

Does anyone know how to make sure the transpiled clj code gets compiled into class files?